# How can i create a script that even if iclose the game is gonna work?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile, scripting

Hey guys i have an issue and i need your help.I try to develop a mobile games.I have an animal in my games and it has 4 slider bar.Health Bar,thirst bar,hunger bar etc..I need a script that it is gonna reduce my health bar value %10 on per hour and it must be do it even if i close the game.I mean even if i dont play the game and my health bar is really low it must be send a notification to me like your health is really low,you should interested with your animal.How to i do, that thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try doing some research in the documentation for getting applications to run functions in the background.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-runInBackground.html
https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-can-i-make-the-game-keep-running-in-the-background-on-android.755699/

Comment: it is not working on android

Comment: It is not really good idea and good practice. Why don't you reduce animals bar when player enter the game. Save entering time of player between save files and you can obtain how much hour player was absent. All idles game do this.

Comment: For notification before closing the game calculate how much hour later you should send notification for low bar then fire notification according to that.

Comment: Because the game has a hunger bar and if it will be zero the player is gonna die.I need to warn the user before the bar value isnt be 0

Answer (score 1):

You can start a foreground service, but that would drain the user's battery and is not a good solution in your case. A better solution would be to schedule your code to run (for example) each hour using the `AlarmManager`.

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

Comment: Thanks man! I will research it.